# What does the { and } mean in CSS different directions?

Tags: html, css

I'm brand new to HTML and CSS and I've been trying to learn it for the past for weeks
books, freecodeacademy, and youtube and so on.

Right now I'm on youtube just looking up how to design my own search engine just for fun. Just trying to understand why he styled it this way, the code is

```
*{
{

}
```

just trying to get a better understanding on the different directions of "{" and "}" and also why we put
a asterisk to it?? sorry for the rookie question, just trying to learn and maybe someone can explain it to me.

Comment: Can you provide code example?

Answer (score 1):

`*`: This is a universal selector.

The Universal Selector is the `*` in CSS. Literally the asterisk character. It is essentially a type selector that matches any type. Type meaning an HTML tag like `<div>` , `<body>` , `<button>`, or literally any of the others. A common use is in the universal reset, like this:

```css
* { 
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```